# Date picker not open correctly when scrolling the panel

Tags: extjs6-classic

I have a panel that contains the number of text fields and date fields.
For example, First I have 15 text fields and then on 16th position I have a date filed.

Initially when I open it works as expected but when I perform the scroll one or more time then date picker not align properly, also the background image should be blank white.

Below is my code,

```
    Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        var fields = [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                padding: 10,
                defaults: {
                    labelSeparator: ''
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field1',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field2',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field3',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field4',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field5',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field6',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                padding: 10,
                defaults: {
                    labelSeparator: ''
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field7',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field8',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field9',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field10',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field11',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }]
            },{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                padding: 10,
                defaults: {
                    labelSeparator: ''
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field12',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field13',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field14',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field15',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field16',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                padding: 10,
                defaults: {
                    labelSeparator: ''
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field17',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field18',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field19',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Date1',
                    anchor: '100%',
                    format: 'd/m/y'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Date2',
                    anchor: '100%',
                    format: 'd/m/y'
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                padding: 10,
                defaults: {
                    labelSeparator: ''
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field20',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field21',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Field22',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Date3',
                    anchor: '100%',
                    format: 'd/m/y'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Date4',
                    anchor: '100%',
                    format: 'd/m/y'
                }]
            }];

        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'Hello',
            layout: 'fit',
            width: '50%',
            scrollable: true,
            items: fields,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Also you can check https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/34n9 in sencha fiddle

Answer (score 0):

First of all. You should not use `layout: 'fit'` like this. A container with this layout should only contain one child item.

Better use e.g.:

```
        layout: {
            type:'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        }
```

But that didn't solve the problem with the datepicker.

I changed to 6.0.2 and in that version the problem seems to be fixed.
I will try to see tomorrow what changed between these minor versions that fixed this problem,
but maybe you could also look.

If you want to test it I created a fiddle for it.

Here's a fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/34nl

Comment: Thank you KaMun, I have override doAlign function and it works.